# Editing make process?

Tags: compiling, raspberry-pi, make, source, u-boot

https://github.com/swarren/u-boot — I have this, need to get the binary so I can finally run something other than Raspbian on the Pi.

The instructions are:
"cd" to directory.. derp.
"make rpi_2_defconfig"
"make all"

However, this is how things turn out ---

```
[*userredacted*@*machineredacted* u-boot-tegra_dev] $ make rpi_2_defconfig
HOSTCC  scripts/basic/fixdep
HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/conf.o
SHIPPED scripts/kconfig/zconf.tab.c
SHIPPED scripts/kconfig/zconf.lex.c
SHIPPED scripts/kconfig/zconf.hash.c
HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/zconf.tab.o
HOSTLD  scripts/kconfig/conf
#
# configuration written to .config
#
[user/machineredacted* u-boot-tegra_dev] $ make all
scripts/kconfig/conf --silentoldconfig Kconfig
CHK     include/config.h
UPD     include/config.h
GEN     include/autoconf.mk
GEN     include/autoconf.mk.dep
CHK     include/config/uboot.release
UPD     include/config/uboot.release
CHK     include/generated/version_autogenerated.h
UPD     include/generated/version_autogenerated.h
CHK     include/generated/timestamp_autogenerated.h
UPD     include/generated/timestamp_autogenerated.h
CC      lib/asm-offsets.s
lib/asm-offsets.c:1:0: error: bad value (armv5) for -march= switch
/*
^
Kbuild:43: recipe for target 'lib/asm-offsets.s' failed
make[1]: *** [lib/asm-offsets.s] Error 1
Makefile:1216: recipe for target 'prepare0' failed
make: *** [prepare0] Error 2
```

How do I go about making it skip even *caring* about anything armv5 related?

Or maybe there's a simple label to satisfy it so that the process completes?

From what I know, this is the author's mistake for not defining such.

edit---
For just a bit of story.. absolutely nothing will boot besides NOOBS and berryboot. The bootcode.bin will not be read at all with it partitioned for Arch (500MB fat16 with boot & lba flags and a second ext4 for root, simple extract to the partitions) nor with the official Ubuntu MATE image. Speaking of berryboot, every OS on the list (which doesn't include Ubuntu or Arch) fails immediately upon trying, complaining of a sha checksum mismatch.
I realize there's a Pi section on SE.. but since all else has failed, and they'll probably just suggest I use NOOBS (which doesn't offer any install of anything anymore besides Raspbian).

So I want u-boot so that I can control booting and add what the hell I want.
If anyone would like to compile it for me (or anyone else having issues with "make" in this or similar instance) then it'd be appreciated <3

Still, let's answer the question. ..maybe not specifically as-worded in the title.

How can this process be edited to allow the completion of the program and to complete and materialize the binary from u-boot's source code?

Comment: Regarding the actual problem as opposed to the actual question (I know, I know, SE is all about questions, not the OP well being, excuse me in advance). There are installation instructions [here](http://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv7/broadcom/raspberry-pi-2) that worked perfectly for me. I found it far easier to use multiple sd cards, than using a (still quite) buggy boot loader. You have to follow the instructions exactly... *No* 500MB boot partition for instance.

Comment: By the way RPi 2 is completely different from RPi (aka RPi 1)

Comment: On what machine are you doing the compilation? With what compiler? It looks like your compilation is choking on the first step that requires a compiler for ARM, so you're either missing a (probably cross-)compiler or not indicating its name correctly. The Pi has an ARM processor, so you *are* going to need to be able to compile for ARM.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to comment out the `-march=armv5` option in the "arch/arm/Makefile"

```
arch-$(CONFIG_CPU_V7)       =$(call cc-option, -march=armv7-a, -march=armv5)
```

But with this I was getting unsupported commands error used as memory barriers written in armv5 assembly.
Most likely these commands (`mcr`) written in `lib/asm_offset.c` need to be re-written in armv7 assembly, or maybe they are not required in v7.
I think these builds were working for earlier version of `gcc-arm-gnueabi` compilers. If there is a possibility of setting the version used in the command-line for building your u-boot then surely it might work (this is purely a guess as I am not aware of that option available).

Comment: After reading some blog response from Robert Nelson I found that instead of passing/using ${CC} as it is in the command line we need to export the CROSS_COMPILER explicitly in the command line and not pass it along with the make commands. This worked for me, hope it works for you as well.